# Navigation bar can be hidden, cannot make visible afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement where I need to hide my navbar toggle only in the login page. I am hiding it with `js` by using `$('.navbar-toggle').addClass('hidden-xs');`. Afterwards, I am making it visible once the login is successful by using `$('.navbar-toggle').addClass('visible-xs');`. However, when I login the navbar is still hidden. The intended behavior is for it to show back up.

Here is my `loginController.js`:

Once I login and inspect my navbar, it is using both `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs`. I want only `visible-xs` to work here. I don't know what went wrong.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `'hidden-xs'` class first.

```
$('.navbar-toggle').removeClass('hidden-xs');
$('.navbar-toggle').addClass('visible-xs');
```